# Understanding the definitions of lattice packing invariants

Tags: geometry

I was recently looking up properties for lattices on WolframAlpha, and I noticed a few properties I hadn't heard of before.  What is the "thickness" and "volume" of a two- or three-dimensional lattice?  What is the lattice "center density"?  I haven't had much luck with a Google search for these values.

I might guess that "volume" refers to the volume of the lattice unit cell.